# Is the word "Language" in "Natural Language Processing" plural or singular, count or mass?

Tags: english, semantics, computational-linguistics, nouns

I want to translate the word **language** in the term **NLP** to the Arabic language. so
I wonder, In **Natural Language Processing**, if the word **language** is **countable** or **uncountable**? whether it is **plural** or **singular**?
After searching the web, one of the main ideas to consider is of https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/language. the meaning #6  where language is countable. but I couldn't settle on a final answer.
I need some help.

Comment: How does this and the comments answer below relate to Arabic? Are you presuming that words are non-count in human language iff they are non-count in English?

Comment: It means the processing of (any given) natural language, not a mass noun.

Answer (score 1):

Natural Language in NLP refers to the linguistic material naturally occurring in a text, whether that is words, phrases, sentences, etc. Since NLP is not specific to a given language and not bound to one particular unit of language, I would go with it being uncountable. The *Language* in NLP is likely closest to definition 8 in the link you provided.

Comment: thank you, but if what you have said is true, I think we would have never used **natural languages** to refer to multiple natural languages, right?

Comment: That's a fair point. The NLP tradition I come from certainly treats language as a bag of language units, but I may not be covering everyone's definition of Natural Language. I am unfamiliar with much of the particulars of Arabic. Since English forces most noun modifiers to be singular, there's no way to tell if underlying the meaning of NLP is a plural idea of natural languages. If Arabic has a readily available translation of Natural Languages, and one can modify the noun Processing with plural noun phrases, then that will probably suit your goal as well.

Comment: What do you think more appropriate, **Natural language texts** or **Natural languages texts**?

Comment: The first is more appropriate, I am certain.

Comment: In this example **language** is uncountable, right? taking into account that the example refer to the digital form of a natural language text

Comment: My instinct is yes, it is uncountable. My interpretation of "Natural Language texts" is "Texts consisting of natural language" so singular and uncountable.

Comment: Do you think that **Natural Language texts** doesn't have the plural interpretation which is texts with maybe one language but probably with many different languages?

Comment: It certainty could! And you are noticing a definite limitation of English. Take something like sandwiches, which is clearly countable. In the phrase Sandwich Eating Contest, sandwich is countable, and implies multiple sandwiches, but we still use singular. To me, the language in NLP and Natural Language Texts is the uncountable material of the texts, but it could also refer to the multiple natural languages in which a text is categorized. I do not envy your challenging position of translating a term of art like this...

Comment: Thank you for this informative comments. You are very kind. But till I settle on a final answer I think I am going with the plural interpretation of _natural language texts_.